# pygame how to actualize rect of sprite

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I'm learning pygame and i am encountering a problem : 
When i'm trying to change the image of the sprite by changing the content of the variable self.image and then self.rect, it doesn't show/acutalize this new image. This is the code, hoping to make myself understood.

```
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
luffy_sprites_ls = pygame.sprite.Group()

class luffy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """docstring pour le personnage"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.lsLuffy = []
        self.lsLuffySauter = []
        super().__init__()
        self.imageAll = SpriteSheet("images/attaquesLuffy.png")
        #loading some img to put them in a lsLuffySauter
        self.image = self.imageAll.get_image(35, 74, 20, 95)
        self.lsLuffySauter.append(self.image)
        self.image2 = self.imageAll.get_image(200, 300, 300,300)
        self.lsLuffySauter.append(self.image2)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 500
        self.rect.y = 500
        all_sprites_list.add(self)
        self.positionX = 500
        self.positionY = 500

    def sauter(self):
        """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """
        self.current_image = self.lsLuffySauter[0]
        self.positionY -= 10
        self.rect = self.current_image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.positionX
        self.rect.y = self.positionY
        luffy_sprites_ls.empty()
        luffy_sprites_ls.add(self)
        #all_sprites_list.update()

#Code to draw in the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.draw((screen))
    luffy_sprites_ls.draw((screen))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `pygame.sprite.Group.draw()` is called, as in `luffy_sprites_ls.draw((screen))`, every sprite in the group has it's `sprite.image` rendered to the screen at `sprite.rect`.

Your `sauter()` function is changing the `luffy.rect`, but it is *not* changing the `luffy.image` (it is changing `luffy.current_image`).

Probably you want something like:

```
def sauter(self):
    """ Called when user hits 'jump' button. """
    self.image = self.lsLuffySauter[0]
    self.positionY -= 10
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = self.positionX
    self.rect.y = self.positionY
```